Does MS-DOS 6.22 support FAT16 filesystems with a single FAT?
I've created a FAT16 filesystem with 1 FAT on Linux (with mkfs.vfat -F 16 -f 1 ...), and I've populated it with files using Mtools mcopy(1). I tried to read those files from DOS running in QEMU:

MS-DOS 6.22: doesn't work, but a FAT16 filesystem with 2 FATs works
FreeDOS 1.3: works
Windows 95 DOS mode: works
Windows 98 DOS mode: works

I tried to use the format command in FreeDOS 1.3 to to format it again with 1 FAT, but the format command doesn't have such an option.
My questions are:

Is it possible to read files from a FAT16 filesystem with 1 FAT on MS-DOS 6.22?
If yes, how should I format it to make it work?


MS-DOS 6.22 includes RAMDRIVE.SYS, which emulates a partition with a single FAT – so it has to be supported at some level.

I patched my MS-DOS kernel (based on 2024 April's release of the v4.00 sources) to allow both diskettes and hard disk partitions with 1 FAT.
This is the patch for hard disks: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/rev/759e0cc9fd9a
...
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [cs:si + FATNUM]
    mov [di + CFAT], cl
    jcxz .none
...

The problem was that the default CFAT field (count of FATs) in the UPB wasn't updated at all. With this patch it is written from the on-disk BPB.
A smaller patch that you could probably more easily apply to the original MS-DOS v6.22 binaries would be to patch the conditions at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/file/759e0cc9fd9a/src/BIOS/msinit.nas#l1714
    cmp byte [cs:Ext_Boot_Sig], EXT_BOOT_SIGNATURE ;AN000;
    jne COPYBPB_FAT     ;AN000; Conventional Fat system
    cmp byte [cs:NumberOfFats], 0   ;AN000; If (# of FAT <> 0) then
    jne COPYBPB_FAT     ;AN000;   a Fat system.
;J.K. Non Fat based media.

Changing the last two instructions to cmp ..., 2 and je would allow to use the "non-FAT" path for BPBs with 1 FAT, which also seems to work, at least as long as you do not try to boot off that partition. The FBIGFAT flag is not written when this code path is used.
This is the patch to support diskettes (floppy disks) with 1 FAT: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/rev/595e3fc43f6f
;MOVBPB PROC    NEAR
    mov ax, word [cs:BPB_IN_SECTOR + DIRNUM]
    mov word [di + CDIR], ax
    mov ax, word [cs:BPB_IN_SECTOR + FATSIZE]
    mov word [di + CSECFAT], ax
    mov ax, word [cs:BPB_IN_SECTOR + RESNUM]
    mov word [di + RESSEC], ax
    mov ax, word [cs:BPB_IN_SECTOR + FATNUM]
    mov word [di + CFAT], ax

ETA: Fixed the diskette patch in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/rev/ed19ee7a531f
    mov al, byte [cs:BPB_IN_SECTOR + FATNUM]
    mov byte [di + CFAT], al

This should only access a byte.

What’s a UPB? This answer seems to assume intimate familiarity with the MS-DOS codebase that most readers will never have.

UPB is my term for the Unit Parameter Block, which links the default DOS block device driver's device units to file systems on the ROM-BIOS int 13h units. It is called Block Data Structure (BDS) in the MS-DOS sources, Drive Data Table (DDT) by the Interrupt List and FreeDOS, and Unit Descriptor (UDSC) by DR-DOS's sources.

So why do you you bring up a term of your own invention without defining it and expect to be understood? What behaviours do those patches change?

So the answer to the question asked is "No, MS-DOS does not support it" (because you have to modify the OS)

@user3840170 Good question, I did assume that context like the question about cylinder boundaries would be known. But it seems I didn't recall that this was asked by another user. As to what the patches do, they make the kernel pick up some fields from the on-disk BPB (aka "superblock") that the kernel previously assumed to have certain fixed values, including 2 FATs & 1 reserved sector. The mentioned RAM drive provides its own DOS block device, outside the msbio module.

FYI MS-DOS 6.22 works well with on-HDD FAT filesystems with more than 1 reserved sector, so I won't have to apply that part of the patch. The other part of the patch (removing shl bx, 1) starts at byte offset 0x26e of MS-DOS 6.22 io.sys. There is no room there for more instructions, but maybe I can make it shorter by dropping the cs: prefix from effective addresses.

If you go for the patch to cmp byte [cs:NumberOfFats], 0 then you won't need the later (FAT FS path) patches. Perhaps it will work even for booting off a HDD.
